# MySQL: employees without project and project without employees

Tags: mysql, join

I want to fetch all the emplyees without project and the project without employees. I don't know where am I doing wrong.

Table structure:

employee: employee_id (PK), employee_name //All employees

project: project_code (PK), project_title //All projects

project_team: project_code (FK), employee_id (FK)  //Bridge table for those of projects and employees are in use.

this is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee e
    LEFT JOIN project_team pt USING (employee_id) WHERE pt.`project_code` IS NULL
    INNER JOIN project p USING (project_code) WHERE (e.`employee_id` IS NULL)
```

Comment: That requires 2 queries.

Comment: I want to do in 1 query @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: Then use UNION between those 2 queries...

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like this:

```
SELECT employee_id AS id_or_code, employee_name AS name_or_title FROM employee e LEFT JOIN project_team pt ON e.employee_id = pt.employee_id WHERE pt.project_code is NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT project_code AS id_or_code, project_title AS name_or_title FROM project p LEFT JOIN project_team pt ON p.project_code = pt.project_code WHERE pt.employee_id is NULL;
```

This way you have the query result in two columns with the first column as the id of employee or code or project and the second column as the name of the employee or the title of the project.

Comment: Sorry, had misunderstood the requirements, the code now is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need FULL JOIN but MySQL don't have it.

Here you can find union solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/4796911/3970250

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to merge 2 different select record into one result set and one way is using union all and then tag each record type something as

```
select 
e.employee_id as id , 
e.employee_name as name, 
'Employee' as type 
from employee e 
left join project_team pt on pt.employee_id = e.employee_id 
where pt.employee_id is null
union all
select 
p.project_code as id ,
p.project_title as name, 
'Project' as type 
from project p 
left join project_team pt on pt.project_code = p.project_code 
where pt.project_code is null ;
```

Here is a test case

```
mysql> select * from employee ;
+-------------+---------------+
| employee_id | employee_name |
+-------------+---------------+
|           1 | A             |
|           2 | B             |
|           3 | C             |
|           4 | D             |
|           5 | E             |
+-------------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from project ;
+--------------+---------------+
| project_code | project_title |
+--------------+---------------+
|            1 | P1            |
|            2 | P2            |
|            3 | P3            |
|            4 | P4            |
+--------------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from project_team ;
+--------------+--------------+
| project_code | employee_id |
+--------------+--------------+
|            1 |            1 |
|            1 |            2 |
|            2 |            3 |
|            2 |            4 |
|            3 |            2 |
|            3 |            1 |
|            3 |            3 |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Running the above query will give you as

```
+------+------+----------+
| id   | name | type     |
+------+------+----------+
|    5 | E    | Employee |
|    4 | P4   | Project  |
+------+------+----------+
```